# Using make modules_install and it results in error target ' ' is not a directory

Tags: linux, module, linux-kernel

I am trying to compile a new custom kernel and this is what i got when i try to install modules using `make --trace`:

```
Makefile:1202: target '_modinst_' does not exist
rm -rf /lib/modules/4.8.17-ARCH 4.1.1-RC1-g9ce0bd6/kernel
rm -f /lib/modules/4.8.17-ARCH 4.1.1-RC1-g9ce0bd6/source
mkdir -p /lib/modules/4.8.17-ARCH 4.1.1-RC1-g9ce0bd6/kernel
ln -s `cd . && /bin/pwd` /lib/modules/4.8.17-ARCH 4.1.1-RC1-g9ce0bd6/source
ln: target ‘4.1.1-RC1-g9ce0bd6/source’ is not a directory
make: *** [Makefile:1205: _modinst_] Error 1
```

From what i know , this happens bacause of the path to my working directory contains invalid characters, but it doesn't seeem wrong to me:

```
/home/student/ws_student/kernel/linux-4.8.17
```

And this is what i got when i looked up in Makefile:

```
_modinst_:
@rm -rf $(MODLIB)/kernel
@rm -f $(MODLIB)/source
@mkdir -p $(MODLIB)/kernel
@ln -s `cd (srctree) && /bin/pwd` $(MODLIB)/source
```

p/s: sorry for my bad english :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not your working directory but **kernel version suffix** which contains "invalid" characters (space):

```
ARCH 4.1.1-RC1-g9ce0bd6
```

As you can see from `make --trace` output, this confuses shell commands in `_modinst_` receipts.

Comment: Can you recommend a solution for this ? Do I need to recompile my kernel ?

Comment: Yes, you need to change that suffix in configuration and recompile the kernel.

Comment: Thanks for your help